# why do we use 'get' before some verbs

Tags: grammar

I was just curious why do we use 'get' before some verbs.

For example, get married, get hungry, and get angry.

Comment: *Hungry, angry* and even *married* (in this context) are not verbs, they are adjectives.

Comment: "get" and "become" are synonyms

Answer (score 2):

While there might be verbs corresponding to those words (to marry, to hunger), in your examples they are adjectives, not verbs.  Get is used to indicate that the person being described reached a point where they could be described with that adjective - "she got angry" tells you that the subject is not always angry, but became angry at some point in time.